# Is there a Harmony API function to fetch both both the HMY and ETH transaction hashes

Tags: etherscan, harmony

It appears that Harmony Transactions have multiple hashes, with the web-based block explorer showing both a Harmony and an ETH transaction hash ([randomly picked example](https://explorer.harmony.one/tx/0x717c401b80d71086ca5651af483756ac4130c469c38027e50a810ab1847c8c7c/)).

This is causing me some issues when I try to reconcile transaction information from multiple extracts, as some of the extracts I've gotten use the Harmony hash and others use the ETH hash.

However when I look at the API docs it doesn't look like either [hmy_getTransactionByHash](https://docs.harmony.one/home/developers/api/methods/transaction-related-methods/hmy_gettransactionbyhash) or eth_getTransactionByHash return both hashes (at least as per the documentation). Is there another richer API I could be using to extract this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the documentation is slightly incorrect. While there's no ethHash field in the returned data according to the documentation there *is* an ethHash field when I call the API in reality.

So an easier problem to solve than I expected.